# What can be written in exchange of Oledb.parameters.AddwithValue() to add a Parameter to a Command?

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am been told that `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` is not good and we should write `cmd.Parameters.Add` instead.
Some of the link referred to me are : 
[Link 1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [Link 2](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). 
I referred the link but the link gave examples with SQL Connection. I am using Oledb Connection everywhere. And `.Add` don't work properly with Oledb Connection.
On digging on stack overflow and other sites I found that almost everyone using `.AddWithValue`. 
Some used `.Add` and I tried their method and got error like **"Must declare a scalar variable."**. 
Again searching the error gives result to use `.AddWithValue`

I am currently using parameters like this

```
 cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE (Col1,Col2,Col3) 
                         VALUES('" & ColVal1 & "','" & ColVal2 & "',?)", con1)
                                'With cmd.Parameters
                                '    .Add(New OleDbParameter("@Trans_Date", TransDate))
                                '    '.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text))
                                'End With
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col3", OleDbType.Date).Value = TransDate
```

And it works fine for me.
So what should I use and How?

Answer (score 0):

That code is wrong.  When you call `AddWithValue`, the second argument is the value and the data type is inferred from that.  If you were going to call `AddWithValue` then it would look like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col3", TransDate)
```

The reason that you should call `Add` instead is that it may occur that the inferred data type does not match what the database actually needs and that can cause problems on some occasions.  Your code is the right pattern but should be calling `Add` rather than `AddWithValue`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Col3", OleDbType.Date).Value = TransDate
```

As it is, you are creating a parameter with a value of `OleDbType.Date` and a data type inferred from that, then you explicitly set the `Value` to `TransDate`.  That's wrong.

Also, the whole point of using parameters is to avoid the issues that can arise form string concatenation and you're using string concatenation anyway.  Don't!  Use parameter EVERY time:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, @Col3)", con1)

With cmd.Parameters
    .Parameters.Add("@Col1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ColVal1
    .Parameters.Add("@Col2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ColVal2
    .Parameters.Add("@Col3", OleDbType.Date).Value = TransDate
End With
```

Comment: So you saying this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Col3", TransDate)` is the proper way? This gives me error as I said. **Must declare the scalar variable @TransDate**

Comment: It also gives me the warning Public Overloads Function **Add(parameterName As String, value As Object)** As OleDbParameter' is **obsolete**: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been **deprecated**.  Use **AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)**.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'

Comment: *"So you saying this cmd.Parameters.Add("@Col3", TransDate) is the proper way?"*. If that's what I was saying then that's what I would have said. If you want to know what I'm saying then read what I actually said.